# Show the following function is increasing

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> If $x<y$ is it true that
>
> $x^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}<y^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}$?

I considered the following function $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}$

I computed $f^{'}(x)={\frac{1}{2n+1}}x^{\frac{-2n}{2n+1}}$

Now $x^{\frac{-2n}{2n+1}}=(\frac{1}{x^2})^{\frac{n}{2n+1}}$

Note that $\frac{1}{x^2} $ is always positive.

But how to show that  $f^{'}(x)$ is positive because we are taking root?

Please help.

Comment: If $\frac{1}{2n + 1}$ is a constant you might find it easier just to call that $t$ or something.

Comment: @TrevorGunn;How would that help?

Comment: Then you're less focused on the having a fraction in your exponent and you can think about the general properties of $x^t$ where $0 < t < 1$.

Comment: Is $x$ assumed to be positive? And what variable denotes $n$?

Comment: X is a real number and n is constant natural number

Answer (score 1):

As you recognised, the claim is true if and only if $f_n(x):=x^{1/(2n+1)}$ is monotonously increasing. However this is not true. For the sake of convenience set $m=1/(2n+1)$, then
$$\frac{d}{dx}f_n(x)=mx^{m-1}$$
which needs to be always positive for $f_n$ to be monotonously increasing. Let's restrict the domain to $(0,\infty)$ to avoid complications with negative powers. Note that anywhere in this domain, $x$ raised to anything is always positive, hence $f_n'$ is positive iff $m$ is. So let's pick $m=-1$ (corresponding to $n=-1$) or any negative number to achieve $f_n'<0$ for all $x$, at which point we get $f_{-1}(x)=1/x$, a decreasing function on $(0,\infty)$. Thus the problem condition is true exactly when $m>0$; or in other words, $n>0$.

**Edit:** in the comments you said that $n\in\mathbb N$, which of course implies $n>0$. Hence, the claim is true.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to use the elementary fact that inverse of any bijective (strictly) increasing function is (strictly) increasing. Note that $x^{2n+1}$ has positive derivative and it is bijective. Its inverse is your function $f$.

[ If $g$ is strictly incerasing, $x<y$ and $g^{-1}(x) \geq g^{-1}(y)$ then $g(g^{-1}(x)) \geq (g^{-1}(y))$ which is a contradiction. Hence $g^{-1}(x) < g^{-1}(y)$].